# Not able to DropShadow of the View If making One corner Round

Tags: ios

I am using this code to make a view with one corner round :

```
-(IBAction)goToSpecificPage:(UIButton *)sender {

 skipButtonBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width-400, 0.0f, 400.0f, 55.0f)];

    UIColor *backGroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.85098039215 green:0.85098039215 blue:0.85098039215 alpha:1];

    skipButtonBackgroundView.backgroundColor = backGroundColor;       

    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:skipButtonBackgroundView.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomLeft                                                      cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];   

    // Create the shape layer and set its path

    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];    
    maskLayer.frame = skipButtonBackgroundView.bounds;    
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;    
    skipButtonBackgroundView.layer.mask = maskLayer;    
    [self.view addSubview:skipButtonBackgroundView];  // Drop shadow    
}
```

But I am not able to drop shadow of the view.

Thanks...

Comment: I want my view with one corner round and drop shadow

Comment: I have solved this problem..actually I need a trick to apply both shadow and round corner animation. For that I added Round corner to one view and shadow to another view and finally added both view under a main view..)

Answer (score 0):

try this one where you are declaring your `UIBeizerPath`

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:button.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(7.0, 7.0)];

maskLayer.shadowPath = maskPath.CGPath;
```

hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are using Shape Layer and stuff. If you just need a drop shadow you can check the method in this [link](http://imagineric.ericd.net/2011/09/20/iphone-drop-shadows/)